# Определение грамматических основ

Tags: синтаксический-разбор

Проверьте, правильно ли я определила грамматические основы?

1. **Им бал, а батюшка таскайся на поклон.**
   *Бал* — подлежащее; *батюшка таскайся* — подлежащее и сказуемое.
2. **Дышал, и ими жил, был занят беспрерывно.**
   *Дышал* — сказуемое, *жил* — сказуемое, *был занят* —сказуемое.
3. **Приехал — и нашел, что ласкам нет конца.**
   *Приехал, нашел* — сказуемое.

Comment: Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его галочкой.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** Бал — главный член, но если выбирать между подлежащим и сказуемым, то сказуемое, так как это состояние «их», но никак не производитель действия.

**3.** Нет — также сказуемое, конца — дополнение.

В остальном все в порядке.

Comment: А мне кажется, Им бал - эллипсис с пропуском сказуемого: им нужен бал, им бал необходим, им подавай бал. Так что всё-таки подлежащее